# Sliding Images with caption underneath in the menu bar of wordpress

Tags: wordpress, menu, carousel

I am working on site.. i need this style of the menu bar in my wordpress site?

is there any plugin to make it happen?

like when the Mouse hover to the menu the carousel of categories appears horizontly

similar to this:
https://www.cremedelamer.com/

help plz

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a plugin, tool, software library, tutorial, book, or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. If you cannot find a resource that does what you want it to, then you'll need to write your own.  Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure if there are any free plugins but you can look for Mega-menu plugins. These produce the type of menu you are looking for.

Comment: i tried, there is nothing i could do.. thats why i posted my own question, btw, thanks for response

Comment: Please do not attempt to answer questions which clearly violate SO community guidelines.  "Questions asking us to recommend or find a plugin, tool, software library, tutorial, book, or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam." https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic